# Generate Desktop path and open csv inside password protected RAR without leaving password trace in terminal [share my knowledge]

Tags: python, pandas, csv, passwords, rar

[Answer my own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.71100121.854382691.1652055536-1853128290.1631197712)

I'm use a *CSV* file as *Dataframe*, but it's inside a password-protected *RAR* file on the *Desktop*.

As each user has a different name generating a different path to the *Desktop*, I will also generate the path automatically regardless of the user's name, so that I can use it on any computer with Windows without having to change the path string.

This will be my contribution to the StackOverflow community today!

Note: feel free to publish improved models for this need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from rarfile import RarFile
from getpass import getpass
import pandas as pd
import os

desktop = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '\Desktop' # create desktop path

rar_files = RarFile(desktop + '\archive_rar.rar', 'r') # open RAR file

specific_file = rar_files.open('file_inside_rar.csv',pwd=getpass()) # open csv file that is inside RAR

print('\033[A\033[A') # Clear row of the password request in the terminal

df = pd.read_csv(specific_file) # Dataframe created from csv file

print(df.iloc[0].values[0]) # row 0, value 0
print(df.iloc[1].values[0]) # row 1, value 0
print(df.iloc[2].values[0]) # row 2, value 0
```

**The string in the terminal will look like this:**

`getpass()` will ask you for the password of the *RAR* file:

```
Password:
```

You will type but the password text will not appear!

When finished typing the password, press *ENTER*.

Then `print('\033[A\033[A')` will clear the existing text in the terminal:

then first `print`:

```
row_1_value
```

then second `print`:

```
row_1_value
row_2_value
```

then third `print`:

```
row_1_value
row_2_value
row_3_value
```